# For which parameter values does the series $\sum 1/(n^\beta + (-1)^n n^\alpha)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $0 < \beta < \alpha \le 1$, for which $\alpha,\beta$ does the series

$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac {1}{n^\beta + (-1)^n n^\alpha}$

converge ?

Comment: The question of $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m)^\beta+(2m)^\alpha}+\frac{1}{(2m+1)^\beta-(2m+1)^\alpha}$ might be easier to handle (moving factors around to force the overall denominator to be $(2m)^{2\beta}-(2m)^{2\alpha}$). Of course these questions are not equivalent, because of conditional convergence issues, but you can try to relate them to each other.

Comment: To put it another way, this rearrangement "roughly" (i.e. modulo lower order correction terms and constant factors) gives you $\frac{n^\beta}{n^{2\beta}-n^{2\alpha}}$, which "roughly" behaves like $n^{\beta-2\alpha}$. So you might expect the requirement $\beta-2\alpha<-1$ i.e. $\alpha>\frac{1+\beta}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $a_n$ for the general term of the series. Also, let  $\delta = a-b$.

Set

$$b_n = a_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{ n^{a}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^a (1+ (-1)^n n^{-\delta})}-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a} \times \left (1- \frac{1}{1+ (-1)^n n^{-\delta}}\right)=(*).$$

Now $$(*)= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^a} \times \frac{(-1)^n n ^{-\delta}}{1+(-1)^n n^{-\delta}}=\frac{1}{n^{a+\delta}}\times \frac{1}{1+(-1)^n n^{-\delta}}.$$

Therefore $\sum b_n$ is a positive series, and by comparison converges if and and only if $$a+\delta =2a-b >1.$$

Since  $\sum (-1)^n /n^a$ converges for all $a>0$, and $a_n = b_n + (-1)^n/n^a$, it follows that  $\sum a_n $ converges if and only if $\sum b_n$ converges, that is if and only if $2a-b>1$.